# Invalid WPF canvas mouse up event

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I tried to create a screenshot function, set the "Canvas" background as a picture, press and raise the mouse to draw a rectangle, and capture the content inside the rectangle, but my mouse up event is always invalid. I searched all kinds of information and tried, all of them seem to be invalid

```
public Bitmap GetScreenSnapshot()
{
        try
        {
            System.Drawing.Rectangle rc = SystemInformation.VirtualScreen;
            var bitmap = new Bitmap(rc.Width, rc.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

            using (Graphics memoryGrahics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
            {
                memoryGrahics.CopyFromScreen(rc.X, rc.Y, 0, 0, rc.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

        return null;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        var screenSnapshot = GetScreenSnapshot();
        var bmp = ImageProcessing.ToBitmapSource(screenSnapshot);
        bmp.Freeze();

        Clipper clipper = new Clipper();
        clipper.bitmap = screenSnapshot;//将图片传过去
        clipper.Background = new ImageBrush(bmp);

        clipper.Show();
}
```

Here, I use a button to create a Window (Clipper) in the main window, and provide the obtained desktop image to Canvas

```
<Window x:Class="MyOCR_WPF.Clipper"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyOCR_WPF"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Clipper" Height="450" Width="800" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Canvas x:Name="canvas" MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown" MouseUp="canvas_MouseUp" Focusable="True" Background="Transparent">
</Canvas>
```

Its mouse up event is always invalid

Comment: i test canvas mouseevent is normal work.you canvas Background set red,See if the window is on top.

Comment: try to set the width and height of canvas for a while and try to set background to a different color then transaparent  just for test

Comment: Probably Mouse up event is setn to some control inside canvas that has captured the mouse event on mouse down. You could try using the hendler with isHandled set to true. In this way canvas will receive the event even if it is marked as handled by some child control.

Comment: @icode Only MouseUP is invalid

Comment: @puko I need picture as background

Comment: @Dmitry I don’t know this well, I need to study it

Comment: i know .. but it is just to test if canvas has height and width.. do you see canvas when he has red background ?

Comment: @puko yes I saw

Comment: What do you mean by invalid ? It is never called ?

Comment: @Dmitry Mouse Up event will not be executed，

Comment: This is my project, you can find out: https://github.com/Uranus-s/MyOCR_WPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Mouseup is invalid because you have drawn a Rectangle on cancas.When mouseup is triggered on Rectangle, the mouseup of Cancas cannot be triggered.
- I tested and found no PreviewMouseUp on Cancas either.
- I used a different solution to your problem.

view

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas x:Name="canvas"  Focusable="False" />
    <Border MouseMove="canvas_MouseMove" MouseDown="canvas_MouseDown" MouseUp="canvas_MouseUp" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```